# numerical solver for stochastic optimal control problems

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, global-optimization

can any one recommend numerical solver (c/c++ library preferred) for stochastic optimal control problems? For deterministic optimal control I found something like that: http://abs-5.me.washington.edu/ocp/index.html Now looking for something similar for stochastic OCP.

Comment: I think this is better suited for computational science over at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: [SLICOT](http://slicot.org/) is another common library for deterministic optimal control. I don't know anything for stochastic control, but I'd be interested, too (especially non-LMI-based solvers for SAREs).

Comment: OP followed @Dirk's advice and reasked this as a [scicomp question](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16034/numerical-solver-for-stochastic-optimal-control-problems).